# Не работает команда и нет ошибки

Tags: python, discord.py

Хочу сделать селект меню, тикеты и тп, но ни одна команда не работает. Тоесть я ввожу команду а от бота никакого ответа и ошибки тоже нет. Как быть?

```
from disnake.ext import commands
from disnake.ui import View, Select

intents = disnake.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', help_command=None, intents=intents)

CENSORED_WORDS = []

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('I am ready!')
    await bot.change_presence(status = disnake.Status.dnd, activity = disnake.Activity(name = 'РєР°РЅР°Р» FaxMax', type = disnake.ActivityType.watching))

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = bot.get_channel(1131562172963635220)

    role = disnake.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=1130740625873051748)

    embed = disnake.Embed(
        title='РќРѕРІС‹Р№ РЈС‡Р°СЃС‚РЅРёРє!',
        description=f'РџСЂРёРІРµС‚ РґРѕСЂРѕРіРѕР№ {member.mention}! РћР·РЅР°РєРѕРјСЊСЃСЏ СЃ РїСЂР°РІРёР»Р°РјРё Рё С‡СѓРІСЃС‚РІСѓР№ СЃРµР±СЏ РєР°Рє РґРѕРјР° РЅР° РЅР°С€РµРј СЃРµСЂРІРµСЂРµ!',
        color=disnake.Colour.green())
    
    embed.set_author(
        name='FaxMaxCommunity',
        url='https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCG7hpn3axNIi_jSg7IyrEAw',
        icon_url='https://cdn.disnakeapp.com/attachments/1126932530315141221/1131566953102856242/Ava_for_FaxMax.png')

    embed.set_thumbnail(url=str(member.avatar.url)[:-10])
    embed.set_image(url='https://cdn.disnakeapp.com/attachments/1126932530315141221/1131566933758718015/static.png')

    await member.add_roles(role)
    await member.send(embed=embed)
    await channel.send(f'РџСЂРёРІРµС‚ РґРѕСЂРѕРіРѕР№ {member.mention}! РќРµ РјРѕРі Р±С‹ С‚С‹ РїРѕР№С‚Рё РЅР°С…СѓР№? Р•Р±Р°РЅР°СЏ С‚РІР°СЂСЊ!')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    for censored_word in CENSORED_WORDS:
        if censored_word in ''.join(message.content.split()):
            print(censored_word, ''.join(message.content.split()))
            dm_message = "Р’С‹ Р±С‹Р»Рё Р·Р°Р±Р°РЅРµРЅС‹ РЅР° С‡Р°СЃ РїРѕ РїСЂРёС‡РёРЅРµ РЅРµРЅРѕСЂРјР°С‚РёРІРЅРѕР№ Р»РµРєСЃРёРєРё!"
            await message.author.send(dm_message)
            await message.author.ban(reason="РќРµРЅРѕСЂРјР°С‚РёРІРЅР°СЏ Р»РµРєСЃРёРєР°")
        else:
            pass

class DDMenu(Select):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(
            max_values=1,
            placeholder='Р’С‹Р±РµСЂРё РёРіСЂСѓ:',
            options = [
                disnake.SelectOption(
                    label='TDS',
                    emoji='рџ’Ґ',
                    description='TowerDefenseSimulator in Roblox',
                    default=True
                )
            ]
        )

    async def my_callback(self, interaction: disnake.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'{interaction.author.mention} РёС‰РµС‚ С‚РёРјРјРµР№С‚Р° РІ РёРіСЂРµ {self.values[0]}')

@bot.command()  # Р’С‹РґР°С‡Р° СЂРѕР»РµР№ РїСЂРё РїРѕРјРѕС‰Рё select menu
async def roles(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(1133736594495524935)
    select = DDMenu()

    view = View().add_item(select)
    await channel.send('Р’С‹Р±РµСЂРё РёРіСЂСѓ:', view=view)

@bot.slash_command()
async def ticket(ctx):
    user = ctx.author
    embed = disnake.Embed(
        title = 'РЎРёСЃС‚РµРјР° РўРёРєРµС‚РѕРІ',
        description = 'РќР°Р¶РјРё рџ“© С‡С‚Рѕ Р±С‹ СЃРѕР·РґР°С‚СЊ С‚РёРєРµС‚.',
        color = 0
    )
    embed.set_footer(text="ticket system")
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction("рџ“©")
    def check(reaction, user):
        return str(reaction) == 'рџ“©' and ctx.author == user
    await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check)
    chan = await user.guild.create_text_channel(name=f'ticket - {user}')
    role = disnake.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="@everyone")
    await chan.set_permissions(role, send_messages=False, read_messages=False, add_reactions=False, embed_links=False, attach_files=False, read_message_history=False, external_emojis=False)
    await chan.set_permissions(user, send_messages=True, read_messages=True, add_reactions=True, embed_links=True, attach_files=True, read_message_history=True, external_emojis=True)

    embed = disnake.Embed(
        title="РўРёРєРµС‚С‹",
        description="РќР°Р¶РјРёС‚Рµ :lock: С‡С‚Рѕ Р±С‹ Р·Р°РєСЂС‹С‚СЊ С‚РёРєРµС‚",
        color=0x00FFFF
    )
    embed.set_footer(text="РЎРёСЃС‚РµРјР° С‚РёРєРµС‚РѕРІ")
    msg = await chan.send(embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction("рџ”’")

    await msg.add_reaction("рџ”’")
    def check(reaction, user):
        return str(reaction) == 'рџ”’' and ctx.author == user
    channel_to_delete = list(filter(lambda channel: channel.name == f'ticket - {user}', user.guild.text_channels))[0]
    await channel_to_delete.delete()
bot.run('tocken')
```

Comment: У вас вместо tocken в коде токен бота?

Comment: Пишет ли бот при запуске `I am ready!`?

Comment: да вместо 'tocken' стоит настоящий токен, и при запуске он пишет i am ready!

Comment: Присутствует ли команда ticket в слэш меню команд?

Comment: только что проверил команду еще раз, ticken  вменю слеш команд отображается. Ввожу команду тикет, а бот только отправляет сообщение, а реакцию нет. Команда roles как не работала так и не работает

Comment: Ок, сейчас подумаю

Comment: может продолжим в дискорде? мой ник deleteduser_o27aft9y

Comment: если вы согласны, то дайте пожалуйста свой ник

Comment: Хорошо, секунду, я вас добавлю

Comment: Отправил запрос

Comment: напишите пожалуйста ваш ник, а то у меня 44 заявки, вас найти трудно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш эмодзи не добавляется из-за того, что в disnake нельзя добавлять эмодзи к сообщениям в слеш-команде. Попробуйте использовать discord.py с кодом

```
check = await ctx.send("Сообщение")
await check.add_reaction(bot.get_emoji(":poop:"))
```

Насчёт селект меню не знаю, может, когда поменяете библиотеку, всё исправится)